# calling uint16 on a rune is big or little endian?

Tags: go, endianness, uint16

I've got the following Go program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    r := rune(249)
    x := uint16(r)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

If I have a `rune r` and call `uint16(r)` on it, is it going to be big or little endian encoded? Does Go default to one? Or does this depend on my hardware?

Comment: See also https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rune` type is an alias for `int32`, and the expression `uint16(r)` is a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), which will retain the lowest 16 bits of the `rune` value. There is no encoding or serialization involved in here.

Little endian or Big endian comes into play when you serialize values into a series of bytes, but that does not happen here.

See this example:

```
r := rune(0x0000fafa)
fmt.Printf("%x\n", uint16(r))

i := uint32(0xfffffafa)
r = rune(i)
fmt.Printf("%x\n", uint16(r))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TnRowYFS1rI)):

```
fafa
fafa
```